# 'ts' Number Field in Database? (ex. 1428881039)

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, timestamp

Thanks to outsourced development, each row in many of my tables has an undocumented field called `ts` with values such as `1428881039`. This is in addition to an actual `created_at` timestamp field with values such as `2015-04-12 17:23:59 MDT`.

These values are passed to this function before displaying it on the web page:

```
public static function display($ts, $created_at, $format = self::FORMAT_DETAILS){
    if ($ts && Session::has('tz_offset')){
        $adminTzOffset = Session::get('tz_offset');
        $final = (int)$ts - (int)$adminTzOffset;
        return date($format, $final);
    }else{
        return $created_at;
    }
}
```

I understand that it has something to do with possibly making sure that the date shown is for the user's correct timezone, but it doesn't even seem to work; it ends up showing the wrong time. Obviously I could just display the `created_at` timestamp, but I understand what this is trying to do here.

Any ideas of what this `ts` field represents?

Comment: does `from_unixtime(ts)` give the same value as `created_at` for each row?

Comment: Interesting. If it's from unix time, that means the number would have been generated from the iOS app when creating the row. `from_unixtime(ts)` gives a value of April, 12 2015 23:23:59. So it is 6 hours off from the correct created_at date, even though it was created in the same timezone as the server.

Comment: Try http://www.epochconverter.com/ - 1428881039 appears to be Thu, 16 Apr 2015 00:56:07 GMT. Does the application have start/end future dates?

Comment: MDT is UTC - 6 hours. So it would appear ts is UTC

Comment: I suppose that this question has technically been answered. We now know it is a unix time stamp in the UTC timezone. However, the actual date that is displayed using this function is still wrong. That's for another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the info garnered from the comments, I would say that the `ts` field is an attempt to record UTC time - since it appears it is 6 hours ahead of your `created_at` field.

The code itself looks like it is using this `$ts` value to calculate a corrected timezone based off a session variable. If you're getting incorrect times, maybe the logged in user has an incorrect timezone setup?

Comment: Thanks so much! It could very well be that in my Laravel or PHP configuration, the timezone has been set to a value which does not agree with the way it was intended to be used.

Comment: It was in fact because in my Laravel configuration, the time zone was set to  America/Denver instead of UTC.